# Oracle Standard Edition Monitoring Tools

Tags: oracle, performance, monitoring

We have 10g and 11g Oracle databases and all of them is Standard Edition.

We need monitoring tools like cloud control for standard editions. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Quest have a suite of such tools - not cheap, but they have a decent rep. in the Oracle community! I had to "repair" a Foglight install once - there's also a host of Open Source solutions out there!

Comment: @Vérace Thanks for the response. Quest has really complicated interface and they don't have standard edition support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go;

1. [Oratify](https://oratify.com) -> I think, This is the best.
2. [Solarwinds](http://solarwinds.com) -> It's fine but I don't know about Standard Edition Support
3. [MyOra](https://www.myorasql.com/) -> We were using about 5 years ago but if you have free time you can try it :)

Comment: Do you know what happened to Oratify?  I came here looking for solutions but the site has been taken down and I can't googlefoo myself any answers on what happened to it. :/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your knowledge about Oracle but We use [Oratify](https://oratify.com) and it has Standard Edition Support.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle now has a broad suite of monitoring tools, known as the [Autonomous Health Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/engineered-systems/health-diagnostics/autonomous-health-framework/index.html) that is free to use to all licensed Oracle database versions.  It tracks both database performance information, and operating system  information.

Answer (score 0):

[Panorama](https://rammpeter.github.io/Panorama.html) as a free open source tool offers several analysis functions for Oracle DB based on AWR and ASH.
For Standard Edition there’s a builtin replacement for AWR and ASH.